# Scree plot scale

Tags: r, statistics

I want to scree plot the result of a pca I peformed. Some of the results of this pca are summarized below with the corresponding scree plot. However, the scale of the scree plot doesn't  represent the results in the table: the variance of the first pc on the table is 71% but only 5% in the plot. Why this discrepancy?

```
                         PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4     PC5    
Standard deviation     3.4603 1.55582 0.62813 0.38341 0.58616 
Proportion of Variance 0.7144 0.05045 0.02683 0.01633 0.01133 
Cumulative Proportion  0.7144 0.76485 0.79168 0.80801 0.81934
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The y-axis of the plot is the variance, i.e. the standard deviation squared:

```
y = prcomp(USArrests)
summary(y)
y$sdev^2
screeplot(y,type="lines")
```

---

The `screeplot` function is actually pretty straightforward to understand. To look at the function, use the `getS3method` function:

```
getS3method("screeplot", "default")
```

The two key statements to look out for are:

```
pcs <- x$sdev^2
```

and

```
plot(xp, pcs[xp], type = "b", axes = FALSE, main = main, 
            xlab = "", ylab = "Variances", ...)
```